# Removing items from the listbox and List <T>

Tags: c#, listbox

How can I remove items from the listbox and the List  at the same time? The User selects has the listbox click the button to remove, it removes the listbox and list  and then updates the listbox.

I'm not using as datasource, I added items in the listbox with foreach

```
mylist.ForEach(delegate(list add)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(list.ITEM + list.VALOR [...]);
}
);
```

Comment: What is this? list.ITEM + list.VALOR[...]

Comment: You say you want to remove from the list and the listbox, but your code adds. Show the code where you try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
mylist.RemoveAt(listbox.SelectedIndex);
```